# FinancialFormula.MovingAverageConvergenceDivergence returning incorrect values

Tags: c#, mschart, financial

I have a series of data and I am calling `DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.MovingAverageConvergenceDivergence, "12,26", "price:Y3", "MACDHisto");`

My problem is that this [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489218.aspx) should return the difference between the two (12 and 26) exponential moving averages and it doesn't. The values it returns are small (as to be expected) but complete nonsense.

I have used a 3rd party tool and another [library](http://ta-lib.org/index.html)  and they corroborate with each other.

As per the MSDN article, the method should calculate the 12 period moving average and the 26 period moving average and store the difference into the output series (MACDHisto). Values are being stored, but they are nonsense and I have no idea how they are being calculated.

Has anyone experienced this occuring?

Comment: I answered a similar question for the TEMA indicator. Take a look and see if it helps you: [How to plot TEMA indicator with Microsoft Chart Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357119/how-to-plot-tema-indicator-with-microsoft-chart-control/32358915#32358915)

Comment: Also, look here for what type of result to expect: [Moving Average Convergence/Divergence Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489218%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @jstreet I know how the formula works, my problem is that it is returning the incorrect values. I have corroborated this with a commercial tool and a third party library that gives just the values. Furthermore the msdn page makes a call to MACD, this method does not exist in financialformula.

Comment: `FinancialFormula.MACD` was probably a typo, they meant `FinancialFormula.MovingAverageConvergenceDivergence`. Post your code and results you're getting.